# DrawRect: How to fill in polygon given an ordered set of points?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, drawrect

Currently in my `drawRect:` method I am drawing a line between every point in my set of points, each represented as a `CGPoint`; however, now I would like to fill in the area that is within the region of these set points. I cannot figure how to do this using the quartz api, is there a way?

Right now, the points are ordered. So it is possible to recognize what point represents the first point of the polygon and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [code sample from Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/QuartzDemo/Listings/Quartz_QuartzPolygons_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007531-Quartz_QuartzPolygons_m-DontLinkElementID_32) shows what you need to do:

```
-(void)drawInContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
    // Drawing with a white stroke color
    CGContextSetRGBStrokeColor(context, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    // Drawing with a blue fill color
    CGContextSetRGBFillColor(context, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    // Draw them with a 2.0 stroke width so they are a bit more visible.
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, 2.0);

    CGPoint center;

    // Add a star to the current path
    center = CGPointMake(90.0, 90.0);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, center.x, center.y + 60.0);
    for(int i = 1; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        CGFloat x = 60.0 * sinf(i * 4.0 * M_PI / 5.0);
        CGFloat y = 60.0 * cosf(i * 4.0 * M_PI / 5.0);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, center.x + x, center.y + y);
    }
    // And close the subpath.
    CGContextClosePath(context);

    // Now add the hexagon to the current path
    center = CGPointMake(210.0, 90.0);
    CGContextMoveToPoint(context, center.x, center.y + 60.0);
    for(int i = 1; i < 6; ++i)
    {
        CGFloat x = 60.0 * sinf(i * 2.0 * M_PI / 6.0);
        CGFloat y = 60.0 * cosf(i * 2.0 * M_PI / 6.0);
        CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, center.x + x, center.y + y);
    }
    // And close the subpath.
    CGContextClosePath(context);

    // Now draw the star & hexagon with the current drawing mode.
    CGContextDrawPath(context, drawingMode);
}
```

Note, this was mentioned in an answer [to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7175886/how-to-fill-a-shape-defined-with-cgpoints-with-gradient-in-ios).

Answer (score 3):

Add your points to an UIBezierPath and then use it's fill method.